# removing tr with a certain class name

Tags: javascript

I have to remove certain tr which have a particular class in a table..I tried the below stuff but it does not seem to work

```
var d1 = document.getElementsByClassName("t1");
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        d1[i].parentElement.removeChild(d1[i]);
    }
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function removeTR (){
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:removeTR()">
        <table>
            <tr >
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="t1">
            </tr>
            <tr class="t1">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your class in the html is `t1` and you're trying to remove `tr1` in the js. Is that a typo just here ?

Comment: `var d1 =` and `d[i].parentElement`...
Well there's your problem. Stay consistent with your naming.

Comment: similarly, your variable is `d1` and you're looping over `d`.  Please fix your question

Comment: You should do it in Jquerry. You can delete any element with just a small bit of code. If you wish I can tell you the Jquerry method

Comment: @TheNoble-Coder Look at the comments on my answer : OP did just do it using jQuery (even while it's as easy to do without).

Comment: @dystroy Great Answer. I  am just kinda advocate for Jquery :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few typo and another more fundamental problem : you can't iterate this way and remove at the same time on a dynamic collection (a live NodeList) as returned by [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

```
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("t1");
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    d[i].parentElement.removeChild(d[i]);
}
```

At second iteration you would try to remove element at index 1 but there still would be an element at index 0 which thus would never be removed.

A solution is this :

```
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("t1");
while (d.length) d[0].parentElement.removeChild(d[0]);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6sGNW/)

Comment: Thanks for replying ..I am pretty new to javascript and didn't quite understand that..but was searching for answers and found out jQuery has  a really easy way so I am using this now $('.t1').remove(); and it works..is this a good way of doing it..Marking ur solution as answer since I asked for javascript which you provided..Thanks

Comment: jQuery is really useful. But you should try to understand what was your bug and how I fixed it.